# Using a C# sha512 hash to communicate a php API

Tags: c#, php, json

I have a web app that want to use payment API that was developed with PHP. The php code for connecting the API works fine, and it is as below:

```
//set variables
$api = 'https://voguepay.com/api/';
$ref = time().mt_rand(0,999999);
$task = 'pay'; 
$merchant_id = '6619-0048444';
$my_username = 'atah';
$merchant_email_on_voguepay = 'omec1010@yahoo.com';
$ref = time().mt_rand(0,9999999);
$command_api_token = 'XPuz39v2RFzgdEUbPqcyTMg8HRkjGA';
$hash = hash('sha512',$command_api_token.$task.$merchant_email_on_voguepay.$ref);

$fields['task'] = $task;
$fields['merchant'] = $merchant_id;
$fields['ref'] = $ref;
$fields['hash'] = $hash;
$fields['amount'] = 20;
$fields['seller'] = 'omec1010@gmail.com';
$fields['memo'] = 'Payment '; 

$fields_string = 'json='.urlencode(json_encode($fields));


//open curl connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $api);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); //we dont need the headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);// data coming back is put into a string
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,2);
$reply_from_voguepay = curl_exec($ch);//execute post
curl_close($ch);//close connection
```

My C# code for connecting the API is below, but when I run the code I get error message the says **"invalid Hash"**. I feel that the hash produced by C# is different from that of PHP.
Which other way can my code be make to get exact out of the PHP hash?

```
class Program
{
    private const string task = "Pay";

    //Replace with your unique command api token
    private const string command_api_token = "XPuz39v2RFzgdEUbPqcyTMg8HRkjGA";

    //your registered email on voguepay
    private const string merchant_email_on_voguepay = "omec1010@yahoo.com";



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        string refl = string.Format("{0}{1}", (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds, new Random().Next(0, 9999999));
        byte[] hash_target = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(command_api_token + task + merchant_email_on_voguepay + refl);
        SHA512 sha512 = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] cryptString = sha512.ComputeHash(hash_target);
        string hashD = BitConverter.ToString(cryptString).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToUpper();


        //load all fields as json and serialize
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
                         { "task", "pay"},
                         { "merchant", "6619-0048444"},
                         { "ref",refl},
                         { "hash",hashD},
                         { "amount", "20"},
                         { "seller", "omec1010@gmail.com"},
                         { "remarks", "Payment"},
           };

        //serialization using Newtonsoft JSON 
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValues);

        //url encode the json
        var postString = WebUtility.UrlEncode(json);

        //calling API with Restsharp
        var client = new RestClient("https://voguepay.com/api/");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("json", json);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

NB: The parameter values I supplied are real data, I set it up for testing purpose, never mind, you can use it to review my work.